# What do I do if my DM wants revenge for when I was the DM?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, problem-gm

I ran my first D&D campaign last year for 8 players (too many I know, but they really wanted to play). One player was super excited and made a detailed character and background. Long story short, the game ended before all its threads were tied up, mostly because I expected to continue this summer. The enthusiastic player was really unhappy with being unable to complete a story arc involving defeating his evil brother and father (the campaign's villain).

Now he's running the next D&D campaign. I got all excited and wrote a detailed backstory that tied my character's backstory into his NPC, but now he says that he wants me to feel the same pain he did. I'm sure he's going to make a mess of the backstory I put so much work into and do bad things to my character.

What should I do? I'm thinking of just playing like I don't care because all this has made me lose interest in his campaign. I'm also thinking of not inviting him to play in the one-shot I'm going to run in August.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG.SE. Please check out our [tour] to get an introduction to how our site works. I'm voting to close this as being primarily a matter of opinion - it's up to you, and you've got social dynamics we don't know about (but if they're a jerk, why would you?). You may also find [the five geek social fallacies](http://www.plausiblydeniable.com/opinion/gsf.html) a useful read.

Comment: Heya! You can check out the [problem-gm] and [problem-players] tag which contains a bunch of questions that are related to yours. Perhaps with some digging (even just the first 5 top-voted questions) can give you some insight and wisdom on how to proceed.

Comment: Daze413 thank you even though many of them are telling that I must talk to him he doesn't listen

Comment: You may also find [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/29677/15469) useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have agreed to all share the same universe and world-setting while player's rotate in and out of the DM position, then you must ***accept that this is part of playing the game in the style you have agreed on.***

If he has "stolen" the world setting that you created, then he is unequivocally in the wrong, and you are right to be annoyed with him - even if it is a "parallel universe" version of your game. However, you have mentioned that he will not listen. If the other players are somehow ok with what he is doing, it would appear that this gaming group is not one you want to be a part of. I cannot work out conflict resolution without knowing you and your entire group, so I would suggest you look at some of the other threads on the site relating to player/DM arguements, for example this one:

[What to do with a mean Dungeon Master?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56157/what-to-do-with-a-mean-dungeon-master?rq=1)

...as well as anything tagged with the [problem-gm] and [problem-players] tags, as suggested by @daze413 in the comments.